# Is there a way to turn on AWS instances using available APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2

As per EC2 documentation, we have action of start and stop instances in the below format

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=StartInstances&InstanceId.1=i-xxxxxxxx&AUTHPARAMS
```

So, what are all the parameters needed for auth params. Also if I try to hit without auth params the response I get is Start instance action not supported.But as per documentation the response should be unauthorised operation. Does this mean I don't have access to turn on in this way?

Also it would be really helpful if there are any other alternatives to turn on AWS remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use an SDK like Java,Node, etc. Or simply use AWS CLI to do this task because all these SDKs provide high level API, which are easier to use.

If you really want to use the REST API and want to understand `AUTHPARAMS`, then here is the answer to that.

The `AUTHPARAMS` is a set of parameters related to authentication which includes `AWSAccessKeyId`, `SignatureMethod` , `SignatureVersion` & `Signature`. Follow this link for more information

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html

If you use the SDKs appraoch you will only need to provide the AWSAccessKeyId with other required params, but you wouldn't need to worry about generating the signature, as that will be done by the SDK/CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it out.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/how-to-ec2.html#prerequisites is this the one you refer to AWS SDK?